# Python requests isn't giving me the same HTML as my browser is

Tags: python, browser, python-requests

I am grabbing a Wikia page using Python requests. There's a problem, though: the requests request **isn't giving me the same HTML** as my browser is with the very same page.

For comparison, [here's the page Firefox gets me](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oxj3br97thq7ulr/yokai-browser.html?dl=0), and [here's the page requests fetches](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwnqtmrkr5zxgmn/yokai-pythonrequests.html?dl=0) (download them to view - sorry, no easy way to just visually host a bit of HTML from another site).

You'll note a few differences ([super unfriendly diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/ujzkg7cq)). There are some small things, like attributes beinig ordered differently and such, but there are also a few very, very large things. Most important is the **lack of the last six `<img>`s, and the entirety of the navigation and footer sections**. Even in the raw HTML it looks like the page cut off abruptly.

Why is this happening, and is there a way to fix it? I've thought of a bunch of things already, none of which have been fruitful:

- Request headers interfering? Nope, I tried copying the headers my browser sends, `User-Agent` and all, 1:1 into the requests request, but nothing changed.
- JavaScript loading content after the HTML is loaded? Nah. Even with JS disabled, Firefox gives me the "good" page.
- Uh... well... what else could there be?

It'd be amazing if you know a way this could happen and a way to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Servers are free to serve whatever you like, based on mood, the phases of the moon, and most of all, what headers your request includes. Firefox sends different headers than `requests`.

Comment: Also, user agents, things loaded via JavaScript, etc.

Comment: This is not, however, `requests` fault. It is the server's choice. You can experiment and copy across headers from Firefox to your `request` code; usual culprits are cookies, the User-Agent header and the Accept* family of headers.

Comment: Then there is the browser itself; it parses HTML received and runs JavaScript code if there is any. Parsing HTML means inserting missing implied elements (such as `<tbody>` into tables) and repairing anything that is broken. Presenting the parsed HTML back at you can easily lead to the order of attributes changing as well.

Comment: @CurtisMattoon: the OP already stated they disabled the JS.

Comment: Then there is the network topology. Is your browser configured to use a proxy at all? Is requests (check for [environment variables](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies)? Are you accessing the server from the exact same IP address?

Comment: @MartijnPieters As mentioned, I copied the headers Firefox uses and used them for the `requests.get()` (User-Agent included), and no dice. That's not the issue. Plus, I'm pretty much entirely certain Wikia does not exclude six images and the navigation for certain IPs / proxies only. Download the HTML files and look at them in your browser - you'll see some fairly obvious, strange differences.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue:

- Identical headers with Python and through the browser
- JavaScript definitely ruled out as a cause

To resolve the issue, I ended up swapping out the *requests* library for *urllib.request*.

Basically, I replaced:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(URL)
```

with:

```
import urllib.request

r = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
```

and then it worked.

Maybe one of those libraries is doing something strange behind the scenes? Not sure if that's an option for you or not.

Comment: I got a similar problem. When I use "request.get(URL)" to get the web page, the remote end closed the connection. But when I use "urllib.request.urlopen(URL)" and "read()" to get the same web page, everything is OK. I don't know why this is happening, but thank you very much @rnhuneau.

Comment: Is it possible that the server is sending different content when you use these libraries instead of normally browsing the web?

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes" when trying to pass a post request objet to it...

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you're not sending the proper header (or sending it wrong) with your request. That's why you are getting different content. Here is an example of a HTTP request with header:

```
url = 'https://www.google.co.il/search?q=eminem+twitter'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'

# header variable
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

# creating request
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)

# getting html
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

If you are sure that you are sending right header, but are still getting different html. You can try to use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It will allows you to work with browser directly (or with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) if your machine doesn't have GUI). With selenium you will be able just to grab html directly from browser.

Comment: As mentioned, it's not the headers. I've tried both leaving them alone and using the ones Firefox sends. Don't want to use Selenium for simple web-scraping, either, but thanks.

Comment: `import requests; 
requests.get(my_url, headers=my_headers)`

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the differences I see are showing me that the content is still there, it's just rendered in a different order, sometimes with different spacing.

You could be receiving different content based on multiple different things:

- Your headers
- Your user agent
- The time!
- The order which the web application decides to render elements on the page, subject to random attribute order as the element may be pulled from an unsorted data source.

If you could include all of your headers at the top of that Diff, then we may be able to make more sense of it.

I suspect that the application chose not to render certain images as they aren't optimized for what it thinks is some kind of robot/mobile device (Python Requests)

On a closer look at the diff, it appears that **everything** was loaded in both requests, just with a  different formatting.

Comment: No, as mentioned, not everything was loaded in both requests. Check the actual files in your browser - you'll see that the bottom navigation (which is the most important part for me right now) and the last six images are missing. In addition to this, as I mentioned, I did try copying the headers (which means the `User-Agent` followed), and no good came of it. The time and render order are definitely not factors either, no question about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue while requesting a page. Then I noticed that the URL which I was using required 'http' to be prepended to the URL but I was prepending 'https'. My request URL looked like https://example.com. So make the URL look like http://example.com. Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Although this may be helpful somewhere, I do not see how it addresses the questions OP has ask.   This would make a better comment perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Requests and Browsers use different ways to render the raw data from WEB server, and the diff in the above example are only with the rendered html.

I found that when html is broken, different browsers, e.g. Chrome and Safari, use different ways to fix when parsing. So maybe it is the same idea with Requests and Firefox.

From both Requests and Firefox I suggest to diff the raw data, i.e. the byte stream in socket. Requests can use .raw property of response object to get the raw data in socket. (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) If the raw data from both sides are same and there are some broken codes in HTML, maybe it is due to the different auto-fixing policies of Request and browser when parsing broken html.

Answer (score 0):

(Maybe my recent experience will help)

I faced the same issue scraping on Amazon: my local machine was able to process all the pages but, when I moved the project on a Google Cloud instance, the behavior changed for some of the items I was scraping.

## Previous implementation

On my local machine I was using  *requests*  library as follow

```
page = requests.get(url_page, headers=self.headers)
page=page.content
```

with headers specified in my class, based on my local browser

```
headers = {
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.137"}
```

but I get incomplete pages using this setup on Google Cloud instance

## New implementation

The following implementation involves *urllib* without the headers

```
req = urllib.request.Request(
                    url_page,
                    data=None
                )
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
page = f.read().decode('utf-8')
self.page = page
```

this solution works on both the machines; before this attempt, I tried also using the same headers and the prolem was not solved, and so I removed the headers supposing that the problem was there (maybe because I was indentifying incorrectly as another client).

So, my code works perfectly and I'm still able to process the content of the pages with *beautifulsoup*, as in the following method which I implemented in my class in order to extract the text from specific portion of the page.

```
 def find_data(self, div_id):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page, features = "lxml")
    text = soup.select("#"+div_id)[0].get_text()

    text = text.strip()
    text = str(text)
    text = text.replace('"', "")
    return text
```