# Script gives me differnt results than the site displays

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a python script to fetch the number of results the site displays. I've tried with two links and they both give me the different result count than what I see in the browser. However, the results that I expect are available in the page source, so requests is supposed to fetch the exact results.

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    'https://www.zillow.com/homes/Houston,-MN_rb/',
    'https://www.zillow.com/homes/Houston,-TX_rb/'
]

for link in links:
    res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    total_result = soup.select_one(".result-count").text
    print(total_result)
```

Result I'm getting:

```
18 results
17,575 results
```

Expected output that I can see when I browse manually using chrome:

```
10 results
8,345 results
```

How can I get the exact result that the site displays?

Comment: try to count the result browsing manually but with javascript disabled, they shuld be the same as the result you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following stack question [Python requests isn't giving me the same HTML as my browser is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773528/python-requests-isnt-giving-me-the-same-html-as-my-browser-is).

Even if the question is old, it seems to stay true (according to my test which is not the Truth :D ). To be honest i have no idea why and would be interesting to dig into the code to understand.

Here is a code with urllib which do what you want and consistently send the same result than browsing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

links = [
    'https://www.zillow.com/homes/Houston,-MN_rb/',
    'https://www.zillow.com/homes/Houston,-TX_rb/'
]

headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}

for link in links:
    req = urllib.request.Request(link, None, headers)
    res=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    #res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    html=res.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    total_result = soup.select_one(".result-count").text
    print(total_result)
```

Hope it helps, and have a good day.

Comment: Yep, it works. I've one question on this though. Why did you use `None` as a parameter within `urllib.request.Request(link, None, headers)`? Thanks.

Comment: I just use the documentation of urllib. Second argument is for data you send for server, look https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request if you want more details (but for example you can a byte-like object to send a file, this kind of things)